# How to fill in SVG paths?

Tags: svg

I created this svg: https://svgshare.com/i/5z1.svg

If you view source you can see that each path looks like

```
<path stroke="black" stroke-width="10" fill="#666" d="M318237,48823 L321987,48823 M321987,48823 L321987,47323 M321987,47323 L318237,47323 M318237,47323 L318237,48823 Z" />
```

However, the svg still has just thin lines and each rectangular path remains unfilled. Is there a way to do this without converting the path into rectangles?

Answer (score 2):

I believe that your paths are not closed and therefore they cannot be filled.

Let's see one path definition:

```
M318237,48823 L321987,48823 M321987,48823 L321987,47323 M321987,47323 L318237,47323 M318237,47323 L318237,48823 Z
```

Every `M` means moving to a point, `L` means drawing a line to a specified point. `Z` means closing the current subpath.

Anything that starts with `M` starts a new subpath. For example:

```
M318237,48823 L321987,48823
```

is a subpath which draws a line

```
M321987,48823 L321987,47323
```

Draws another line but without connecting it to the previous subpath, creating an unclosed path. It should be:

```
M318237,48823 L321987,48823 L321987,47323
```

and so on.

Full closed path:

```
<path stroke="black" stroke-width="10" fill="#666" d="M318237,48823 L321987,48823 L321987,47323 L318237,47323 L318237,48823 Z" />
```

The last line `L318237,48823` can be omitted because that's what `Z` does anyway.

The definition could be also simplified using `H` and `V` commands since you have only straight horizontal/vertical lines.

Comment: so it seems like if I just delete the 2nd, 3rd, and 4th M, that should make them closed paths?

Comment: @BigBoy1337 Exactly. `M` is moving to a new position, starting a new path. Otherwise you continue from the current position, with the current path. Also note that `Z` draws a line from your last position to the start of the path, therefore you don't really need the last line.